# how to stop the infinite loop and exclude the directories?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Could you please someone suggest , how to stop the infinite loop and exclude the directory from the below script ( Here i have to exclude only the logs). Once if the files are copied from source to destination, then the loop should be stopped.

```
    #!/bin/bash

source=/home/ec2-user/source
dest=/home/ec2-user/destination

while true; do
        rsync -arv --exclude '/home/ec2-user/source/IntegrationServer/instances/default/logs' $source/ $dest
            sleep 1
    done
```

Comment: Why is there a loop at all?  Just get rid of it.

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude the directory"?  Do you just want `--prune-empty-dirs`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell, Thank you for the response.  I can rid of the while condition , then rsync will work as incremental backup right ?

exclude the directory means , logs folder i dont want to backup along with that some other folder i dont want the backup. In that case how can i exclude those directories while using the rsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected. You can add the while loop if you wish for it to continue forever.

```
#!/bin/bash
source=/home/ec2-user/source
dest=/home/ec2-user/destination
rsync -arv --exclude IntegrationServer/instances/default/logs $source/ $dest
```

The exclude needs to be relative to the source. So I removed the part common to the source.